# Which set does this windshield piece with a hanging green head come from?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

This is a windshield piece 2x 4 x 2, 4594. It has a printed green face on it. What set does it come from?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

That would be

[Part # 4594 : Windscreen 2 x 4 x 2 Vertical with HP Shrunken Head Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4594px1#T=C&C=12)

from [Set # 4755: Knight Bus](https://brickset.com/sets/4755-1/Knight-Bus)

[image]

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Dre_Head